# TensorFlow doesn't seem to install

Tags: tensorflow, installation

I have those warnings:

> 2017-09-26 14:50:45.956966: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>
> 2017-09-26 14:50:45.956986: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>
> 2017-09-26 14:50:45.956990: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>
> 2017-09-26 14:50:45.956996: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

So, based on what I found on internet, I then followed this link:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

However, when I try:

```
$ python
```

and :

```
# Python
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

The output should be : `Hello, TensorFlow!`

However, I don't get that at all...

```
emixam23@pt-mguittet:~/Workspace$ python
Python 3.6.2 (default, Sep  4 2017, 16:58:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2017-09-26 14:56:33.905065: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-26 14:56:33.905096: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-26 14:56:33.905105: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-26 14:56:33.905112: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
>>>
```

Even after I installed it, I still have the warnings, why so? I used Xcode 7.3 and I didn't put the GPU in the `./configuration` process.

Any idea? :/ Thank in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can mask these warnings like so:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

Notice that your program still output 'Hello, TensorFlow!', just simply after all of the warnings regarding SSE4.2.

Comment: By doing that, you only hide log which doesn't answer to my question, doesn't? Thank for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saying it doesn't seem to install?

You are getting what you expected (Hello, Tensorflow!) but you are also getting these warnings. Regarding the warnings, they have been discussed here: [Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u?rq=1)

Regarding the "b'" before Hello, Tensorflow!, see [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal).

Hope it helps.